# Get the most recent directory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the most recent directory by date in JavaScript? Or if this not possible, the directory with the highest number?

Because I have a folder with versions, and I want to use JavaScript to select the latest version and redirect to that folder.

***To be more clear, I want this because GitHub pages only supports HTML, CSS and JS.***

```
folder/
    1.0/
        index.html
    2.0/
        index.html
    3.0/
        index.html
    index.html
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you using javascript with? Node.js? Windows Scripting? A browser? ASP?

Comment: I am afraid I think this approach wont work in context of browser. (correct me if I am wrong). if you have API support, then why dont you pass the appropriate version and use it dynamically ? make sense ?

Comment: @agpt I know there are many other ways, but it's @ GitHub pages. GitHub pages only supports HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I want a script that automatically finds the newest directory. I thought this was possible with JavaScript...

Answer (score -1):

If you are using nodejs, you can use `fs.stat(path, [callback])` which will give you `mtime` as part of the stats object in the callback

`mtime` is the time at which the file/folder was last modified.